# Sails.js how can i get the name of image after upload

Tags: javascript, mysql, sails.js

I want to get the name of image and insert it in MySQL after uploaded it. 
Turn out I get the store images path instead. like **E:\work\assets\pic_items\98046f37-ac7a-42cc-996.png** on MySQL
i only want name of image after uploaded it.

How can i do that?

This is my controller

```
update: function (req, res){
    var id = req.param('id');
    var category_id = req.param('category_id'); 
    var title = req.param('title');
    var description = req.param('description');
    var width = req.param('width');
    var height = req.param('height');
    var price = req.param('price');
    var picture_path = req.param('picture_path');


    console.log(id);

    req.file('picture_path').upload({dirname: "../../assets/pic_items"},function (err, uploadedFiles){
        if (err) {
            return res.send(err);
        }   
        console.log(uploadedFiles);
        if (uploadedFiles.length === 0){
            console.log(uploadedFiles);
            return res.serverError('no file was uploaded'); 

        }
        picture_path = uploadedFiles[0].filename;
            picture_path = uploadedFiles[0].fd.replace(/^.[\\\/]/, '');


    Item.update({id:id},{category_id:parseInt(category_id),title:title, description:description, width:width, height:height, price:parseInt(price), picture_path:picture_path}).exec(function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return res.send('life is suck');
        }
            res.redirect('/item');
        });
    });
},
```

Comment: I believe I have provided an example for what you are looking for in another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43992808/how-to-serve-images-in-a-folder-in-sailsjs/43999359

Answer (score 0):

```
picture_path = uploadedFiles[0].filename;
            picture_path = uploadedFiles[0].fd.replace(/^.[\\\/]/, '');
```

I believe it is in `uploadedFiles[0].filename`. Why are you overriding it with `uploadedFiles[0].fd.replace(/^.[\\\/]/, '')` ?

Comment: because when i use uploadedFiles[0].filename. I get original name of image. but i want the name after upload it. So i override it and i got all the path where it stored images.